# Is there any upper limit for the number of posts that can be created with wordpress

Tags: posts, performance

Simple question as in title. What is the maximum number of posts that can be written in a blog?

Answer (score 2):

There is no theoretical limit on the amount of posts that can be stored and served. However, there will be a limit on what your server can achieve, in terms of database size, hard disk space and processor capacity. On an ordinary dedicated server you should be fine as long a you stick with a couple of 100.000s of posts (I run an installation with 100.000 posts and 1.000.000 comments which is doing just fine).

Comment: Simple questions don't always have simple answers!  I'm sure we could find a theoretical upper limit, starting with some crazy [Graham's number](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTeJ64KD5cg) - *"a number so epic it would collapse your brain into a black hole!"* and work us down from there ;-)

Comment: We might also wonder what would happen if WordPress would be ported to a [blackhole computer](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/black-hole-computers-2007-04/) (too many RAM chips would collapse into a blackhole) or how it would be handled in quantum computers ;-)  Just kidding ;-) PS: Database sharding might also help sites with millions of posts.

Comment: One could also look at MySQL & PHP for *type* size limitations.

Comment: Nice links @birgire +1

Comment: @birgire I disagree. There is no equivalence between "there is" and "I'm sure we could find". I'm sure I can find a way to recursively code myself out of any max-int you find in MySQL and PHP. The size of the universe is irrelevant for theoretical considerations. So, if you want to convince me, show me da number. ;-)

Comment: "theoretical" can also mean from the perspective of physics, where the universe matters ;-) @cjbj

Comment: @birgire. No, that's a matter of available resources, not fundamentally different from server capacity. There is no theory outside mathematics. ;-)

Comment: The way I see it, is that we must additionally restrict and map our playground to models of our Universe given by theoretical physics ;-) So I think we have a different understanding of "theoretical" here ;-) @cjbj